# Why didn't Boeing make the Sky Interior for the Boeing 777?

Tags: commercial-aviation, boeing, boeing-777, cabin-design

Generally, Boeing has attempted to make the interiors of their aircraft as similar as possible, with one "unified" interior across different aircraft (i.e. based on a single "look and feel" for you UX enthusiasts), such as the older (but still fairly new) "Signature Interior" (debuted with the Boeing 777) and the newer "Sky Interior" (debuted on the Boeing 787).

When a new interior style was created, it seems like Boeing generally tries to copy that same interior to other aircraft. For instance, the Signature Interior was also used on earlier 737 NG and later 747-400 and 767 aircraft (with a retrofit offered), and the Sky Interior was used on later 737 NG (conflicting information about retrofits), 737 MAX, and 747-8.

While it seems from the above that Boeing is pushing new interiors onto older aircraft, including the 737, 747, and 767, this doesn't seem to be the case for the 777; even those coming off the assembly line today still have the original Signature Interior. Why didn't Boeing make a Sky Interior for their 777?

To make it clear what I'm talking about, here are some images and descriptions of each interior:

#### Signature Interior

[image: Delta Air Lines 777-200 Signature Interior]

<sub>Source: [Airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Delta-Air-Lines/Boeing-777-232-LR/1346267)</sub>

Notes:

- Middle section overhead bins and passenger service units appear integrated with the ceiling.
- Side passenger service units are angled.
- Overhead bin open handles can only be pulled one way.
- The interior fittings are beige.

#### Sky Interior

[image: Lufthansa 747-8 Sky Interior]

<sub>Source: [Lufthansa Magazin](https://magazin.lufthansa.com/xx/en/fleet/boeing-747-8-en/)</sub>

Notes:

- Middle section overhead bins and passenger service units appear attached to, rather than integrated with, the ceiling.
- Side passenger service units are almost completely horizontal.
- Overhead bins have open handles that can be pulled either way.
- The interior fittings are white.

---

Keep these mind's answer points to a Ukraine International Airlines marketing material that advertises the "Sky Interior" for their 777s. However, clicking through the link shows a picture of their 777, but it has the same Signature Interior as above.

Comment: Note that the 777X series _will_ have either the Sky Interior, or something very close.

Comment: I observe that the "Signature" picture appears to show First or Business class, whereas the "Sky" picture clearly shows Cattle class.

Comment: @MartinBonner The interior fittings I refer to in the question don't include the seats.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is an exception, but Ukraine International Airlines seems to claim that they have a Sky Interior in their 777. **User gparyani comments that this claim may be mistaken. I'll leave this answer here in case somebody else independently comes up with the same thing.**

> Welcome on board modern Boeing 777-200ER airliner! The aircraft’s quiet and cosy cabins are equipped with comfortable reclining seats, contemporary Sky Interior [...]

https://www.flyuia.com/ua/en/services/long-haul-b777

Comment: Scrolling down towards their images shows the standard Signature Interior, not the Sky Interior.